# how to print f[r] and f[k] values in an output file for each value of r and k in mathematica?

Tags: file-io, wolfram-mathematica

How can i print the f[r] and f[k] values in an output file along with r and k values using mathematica?
Is there any way I can automate the export of this output to a .txt file without having to re-write the Print[] commands?

Comment: You are looking for the `Export[]` command, probably combined with `Table[{ x, f[x]}, {x, init, end, step}]`. BTW ... did you visit the [Mathematica Q&A site](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com) yet?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach to saving Mathematica expressions is to use the `Save` function.  You could write

```
Save[filename,x]
```

and Mathematica will save the definitions associated with variable `x` into the file you've named.  Note

- `Save` appends to an already existing file;
- expressions are written in `InputForm`;
- you can load the expressions back into your workspace using the `<<` (aka `Get`) function, which reads *and evaluates* the expressions stored in a file.

How you actually use `Save` to store your data is up to you.  You might, perhaps, assign the results of a call such as `Table[{k,f[k]},{k,min,max,step}]` to a variable and save that result variable, which will appear in the file as a table of `k,f[k]` pairs.

Since `Save` appends to an existing file you could, if you are using loops, save a `k,f[k]` pair at each iteration.  But why would you be using loops in Mathematica ?